# JAX-RS : Get an array from url

Tags: url, jax-rs

I try to intercept the parameter from this URL

http://myapi.com/myobject?filter[0][name]=location&filter[0][value]=FR&filter[1][name]=type&filter[0][value]=real.

How can i declare this "filter" param on my méthod to get all this map values ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can be done "automagically", I would do something like this:

```
@Path("/myobject")
@GET
public Response myMethod(@Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
     MultivaluedMap<String, String> queryParams = uriInfo.getQueryParameters(); 
     // parse the map keys
}
```

In the queryParams map you will have `{"filter[0][name]" => location, filter[0][value] => FR, ...}` key-value pairs, which you need to parse further. Parsing keys let you reconstruct original map from the query. That would not be beautiful piece of code, but will work.